# How to increment variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried to increment variable value but not working.How to increment value depends on passing number?

```js
function getVal(val) {
  var checkProductId = val;
  var g = checkProductId.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  var q = Number(g);
  var k = q++;
  console.log(k);
}

getVal("CSS10"); //out put should be in console.log(k);   11
getVal("CSS11"); //out put should be in console.log(k);   12
```

Comment: Don't try to be clever. `var k = q + 1;`. The technical answer is that `++q` would work too (but it also *changes* `q`)

Comment: could you please tell us the error or what output you get now?

Comment: `var k=q++;` is basically `var k=q; q=q+1;` `var k=++q;` would be like `q=q+1; var k=q;` but actually, all you need is `console.log(++val.replace(/\D/g, ""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using post increment operator on **q** while you want to use the incremented value, so you should be used pre increment operator like `++q`

```js
   function getVal(val){

    var checkProductId =val;
    var g = checkProductId.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var q = Number(g); 
    var k=++q;  
    console.log(k);

    }

    getVal("CSS10");   //out put should be in console.log(k);   11
    getVal("CSS11");   //out put should be in console.log(k);   12
```

this should work

you can watch this to understand more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K55gqsS38XY

Comment: Any other way is there?

Comment: other way for what ? did you watch the video link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
function getVal(val) {
   var id = Number(val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
   var increment = id + 1
   console.log(increment);
 }

 getVal("CSS10");   //out put should be in console.log(k);   11
 getVal("CSS11");   //out put should be in console.log(k);   12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do pre-increment.
var k = q++; will assign value of q to k first and then do increment.
So change statement to var k = ++q; which do increment first and then assign value to k.